# Difficulties with a Makefile

Tags: makefile, coq

So I'm trying to install the Homotopy Type Theory library for Coq from github following [these instructions](https://github.com/HoTT/HoTT/blob/master/INSTALL.md). Running the command `etc/install_coq.sh` sets it off messing with a bunch of files before it hits an error as so:

```
$ make clean
make: *** No rule to make target `clean'.  Stop.
```

Apparently there's one or more bugs present within `Makefile.am`, and according to what I've read while googling the issue it's likely related to improper whitespace. Running `make clean` myself yields the same thing:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `clean'.  Stop.
```

Meanwhile running `make -f Makefile.am clean` yields:

```
Makefile.am:4: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Lines 4-6 in the file are simply:

```
if make_hoqide
  bin_SCRIPTS += hoqide
endif
```

What's wrong with that that's causing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Makefile.am is generally paired with Makefile.in; these need to be processed with automake or configure before you get a usable real Makefile.

If you've got a script "autogen.sh" in your top-level source directory, run that
first, then configure:

```
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure
$ make
```

This is, in fact, step 3 of the instructions that you linked to. Perhaps the install_coq.sh script isn't finding all of the dependencies that you need?